# __ANDROID__ macro suddenly not defined

Tags: android, macros, android-ndk

I'm working on an app which uses NDK (all I'm writing happened both on r6b and r8d)

Everything was working fine, and I wanted to start and try debugging my C code.

I followed this http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin tutorial,
but `NDK_DEBUG = 1` tag to my build command, suddenly I started getting errors in the code which didn't go away even after removing that tag, changing from Android 4.2.2 back to 2.2, changing the NDK I was using, or anything else I could think of.

The problems happens now inside statements like this

```
#ifdef __ANDROID__
some cool android code
#else
some pretty awesome iOS code
#endif
```

what happens it that the `__ANDROID__` is for some reason not define, causing eclipse and `ndk-build` to try and compile the iOS code instead of the Android's

Reverting everything I did didn't seems to have any effect. Restarting eclipse didn't as well. Cleaning the project, completely delete `libs` and `obj` directories didn't work too..

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Maybe it's worth adding that the build itself, using ndk-build completes successfully.
I think it might be an eclipse issue, but even if so, it still an error and I can't launch the app

Also, just in case, restarting the computer didn't work either.

EDIT 2:
The problem exists on another computer running the same workspace over network, my guess was something related to the workspace, so I tried deleting `.metadata` folder and adding the project again.

Deleting the `.metedata` folder fixed it the 1st time, but after a few minutes (in which I managed to build and run the app on my tablet) the same issue returned, and deleting the `.metadata` didn't work

**EDIT 3:**

Still no go.

However, I can confirm that it's not a project specific problem, as all the projects that has Native support in eclipse now do this.

Other things that doesn't work:

- creating an empty project, adding Native support.
- Completely changing to another unrelated workspace and perform the above tests
- Downloading fresh version of eclipse (juno), `CDT` & `ADT` (was using the eclipse ADT bundle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else encounters this issue:

I opened the workspace on another computer (Workspace is in a Dropbox folder), and the problem was still there on the other computer, which could only mean a workspace issue, so I delete the .metadata folder from the workspace.

I had to re-add the projects, but after doing so, everything seems to work now.

Answer (score 14):

Just so you know:

- when you work with `Android.mk` file(s) and `ndk-build`, the `ANDROID` macro is predefined (see `-DANDROID` extra C flag when building with verbose outputs),
- but if you use the Android Standalone Toolchain, then `__ANDROID__` is predefined instead.

So I suggest you to use:

```
#if defined(ANDROID) || defined(__ANDROID__)
  /* ... */
#endif
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, doing so didn't change anything. Still the same problem..

Comment: What I suggest you is to trigger verbose outputs with `ndk-build V=1` and inspect what's going on within your build commands, i.e. is `-DANDROID` present?

Comment: Thanks, I did it now, and `-DANDROID` is there. Also, it seems that the C code is compile well, the `.so` library file is being generated. it's as if eclipse itself doesn't recognize these flags, cause even though the c code appears to have error when viewed in eclipse, it compiles as it should

Answer (score 5):

Apparently `__ANDROID__` is a specific [GCC macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.4/gcc/GNU_002fLinux-Options.html) that it supposed to define internally whenever correct options are provided. However, since control over options is largely delegated to NDK, one should not rely on `__ANDROID__` macro being ever defined. The compiler behind NDK might not be GCC for all we know (or care). When working with NDK, check for `ANDROID`.

Edit: clang now also defines `__ANDROID__` macro