# Distinguish between NDK build and Android build

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, c-preprocessor

I have a native library I build that needs to be build in the Android build, but can also be built using the **NDK**.
How can I distinguish using the preprocessor between **NDK** build and Android build.

```
#ifdef __ANDROID__

#ifdef NDK ??? // does ndk export some symbols I can use here ?

foo();

#else // Android tree build

foo2();

#endig

#endif // __ANDROID__
```

Comment: `ndk-build` defines `ANDROID` while the standalone toolchain defines `__ANDROID__`: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15335544/1688185. Is it what you are asking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use one of the platform build environment variables to distinguish two builds. That could be [`DEVICE_NAME`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/master/core/device.mk), [`TARGET_DEVICE`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/master/core/product_config.mk), [`PLATFORM_VERSION`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/master/core/version_defaults.mk) or anything else that's defined beyond my project's scope. And, depending on that environment variable, I'd define a flag in my project's **Android.mk**:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := foo

ifeq ($(DEVICE_NAME),)
    # no device name is defined, got to be an NDK build
    LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DANDROID_NDK
endif
```

and then in **foobar.c**

```
#ifdef ANDROID_NDK
    foo();
#else
    foo2();
```