# "__ANDROID__ macro is not defined

Tags: android, macros, defined

I am working on APP includes c++ code. I am using     __android_     macro to distinguish the IOS and C++ specific code in eclipse ADT.

ex.

```
#ifdef __ANDROID__
#define android
#endif

#ifdef (android)
//Android specific code
#else
//IOS specific code
#endif
```

It was working fine since couple of moths, but Suddenly the macro is not defined in ADT.

I have tried:

- Creating new workspace
- using additional "ANDROID" macro
- using different ADT version.

I have referred the thread
[__ANDROID__ macro suddenly not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328751/android-macro-suddenly-not-defined)
But I guess its been left by the user and the solution is not yet provided..

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you just add -D__ANDROID__ to the command that compiles the code when building for Android?

Comment: thank you michael for comment...
well yes.. but this macro needs to be added to .mk file explicitly when we compile the project using command line...
but when we use native support in eclipse its the NDK toolchain which adds this necessary flag. IN my case I am using Eclipse and it was working fine till couple of days back... but suddenly its not defined :(..